# Presenting modal view over partial page curl modal view

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, storyboard, modalviewcontroller

I have my main menu embedded in a navigation controller. The settings button performs a modal segue to show my settings page which is half a page shown using the partial page curl.
Now on the settings I have a 'legal' button which I want to just display a full screen UITextView with all my legal stuff.
The problem is, when I display the legal view controller using a modal segue, it displays behind the partial page curl.
If I try using a push segue, it crashes because there is no Navigation controller as the settings is shown modally.

Is there a way to present a modal view over the top of a partial page curl?

Thanks

Comment: Post a screen shot will be really helpful for us to understand the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Best option I can think of is **managing all your segues in your initial main menu controller**.

For example, you can write a delegate method such that, if the user hits 'legal', you dismiss the modal view (from within  your main menu controller's .m) using a delegate method, and then in that same method present a new modal view controller for the settings page (with it's parent being the main menu view controller, which can then have another delegate method to dismiss the legal page and present the settings menu).

Comment: Yes I think this may be the only way to do it. I did try it briefly, but the main menu was obviously calling viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear etc.. which causes problems. I can I can wrap them all in a BOOL var.